# jquery div over layer when window scroll, div stay at same position

Tags: jquery

```
var stickyTop = $('#r_ads').offset().top;

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var windowTop = $(window).scrollTop();

    if (stickyTop < windowTop) {
          $('#r_ads').css({ position:'fixed', 'top':0, 'left':'68%' });
        }
    else{$('#r_ads').css('position','inherit');}
});
```

I have a advertisment div, use jquery stay at same position when window scroll.

I set the position fixed top:0 & left 68%

However when user zoom in or out, the div will over layer other content because fixed.

is any way to fix this?

Comment: did you try to make it absolute positioned?

Comment: You need to detect the screen width and determine if the ad div has enough space or not.

Comment: var stickyLeft = $('#r_ads').offset().left; I did this, but if user use zoom after page load, the position will change.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (stickyTop < windowTop){$('#r_ads').css({ position:'relative', 'top':windowTop - 20});}
```

Try this, change to relative, than use origional windowTop - the height you want.